# Use ansible k8s module behind a proxy

Tags: bash, kubernetes, proxy, ansible

I try to run some ansible tasks with the k8s module. Locally this works perfect, but on my Jenkins instance, it fails with the following error message:

> ...
>
> MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or
>   ResponseError(cause))\nurllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2]
>   Name or service not known',))\n", 
>       "module_stdout": "", 
>       "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
>       "rc": 1 }

I am quite sure this is because the Jenkins requires a proxy to communicate to the outside world. I´ve seen how to set up ansible for using a proxy, but that does not seem to work with the k8s module. Any ideas? Here´s what I´ve tried so far:

```
 - hosts: ansible_server
   connection: local
   gather_facts: no
   environment:
    https_proxy: "xxx"
    http_proxy: "xxx"
   tasks:
    - name: Gather facts to check connectivity
      k8s_facts:
       api_key: "{{api_key}}"
       host: "{{cluster_url}}"
       kind: Project
      register: listed_projects
```

PS: I added the -vvv flag and can see that it tries to use the proxy somehow:

> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0' Using module
>   file
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s_facts.py
>    PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1fHx5f6/tmpDUhlNa TO
>   /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570565569.96-190678136757098/AnsiballZ_k8s_facts.py
>    EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x
>   /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570565569.96-190678136757098/
>   /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570565569.96-190678136757098/AnsiballZ_k8s_facts.py
>   && sleep 0'  EXEC /bin/sh -c
>   'https_proxy=xxx
>   http_proxy=xxx
>   /usr/bin/python
>   /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570565569.96-190678136757098/AnsiballZ_k8s_facts.py
>   && sleep 0'  EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r
>   /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570565569.96-190678136757098/ >
>   /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'

Comment: i would focus on the `Name or service not known` error. seems some of the hosts involved cant resolve the mentioned host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @ilias-sp but it also appears that [`k8s/common.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.5/lib/ansible/module_utils/k8s/common.py) does not support the [`configuration.proxy` attribute](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v10.0.1/kubernetes/client/configuration.py#L103), , and as best I can tell `urllib3` does not honor those proxy environment variables the way "normal" urllib does, opting instead to use its own `ProxyManager` that is driven by an explicit constructor kwarg

However, thanks to the "override" mechanism of ansible, I believe you can test this theory:

1. Copy `k8s_facts.py` into the `library` folder of your playbook
2. Modify it to expose `proxy` in the [`AUTH_ARG_MAP`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.5/lib/ansible/module_utils/k8s/common.py#L128-L139), which I believe the patch below will do (the patch is against v2.8.5 so you may need to fiddle with it if your version is different)
3. Explicitly set your `proxy:` attribute on your new `k8s_facts` module and see if it works

   ```
   - k8s_facts:
       host: api-server-whatever
       kind: Project
       proxy: http://my-proxy:3128
   ```
4. Assuming it does, [open an issue in ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) to let them know

```
--- a/library/k8s_facts.py  2019-10-08 22:23:24.000000000 -0700
+++ b/library/k8s_facts.py  2019-10-08 22:24:50.000000000 -0700
@@ -130,13 +130,14 @@
 '''


-from ansible.module_utils.k8s.common import KubernetesAnsibleModule, AUTH_ARG_SPEC
+from ansible.module_utils.k8s.common import KubernetesAnsibleModule, AUTH_ARG_SPEC, AUTH_ARG_MAP
 import copy


 class KubernetesFactsModule(KubernetesAnsibleModule):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
+        AUTH_ARG_MAP['proxy'] = 'proxy'
         KubernetesAnsibleModule.__init__(self, *args,
                                          supports_check_mode=True,
                                          **kwargs)
@@ -163,6 +164,7 @@
                 namespace=dict(),
                 label_selectors=dict(type='list', default=[]),
                 field_selectors=dict(type='list', default=[]),
+                proxy=dict(type='str', required=False),
             )
         )
         return args
```

Comment: Wow, many thanks for that elaborate answer. I applied the patch as suggested and it works now. I will create the issue as suggested by you. Thank you very much.

Comment: One more thing, can you please help me to achieve the same for the "normal" k8s module? I tried that, but my python skills are too limited to do this in an adequate amount of time

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to take it up with the ansible folks, or get one of the "coder for hire" services to straighten that Python problem out for you